# Chaining Controller Actions to one Route

Tags: sails.js

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here. I'm following this example here: https://gist.github.com/mikermcneil/5737561.

I want to chain two controller actions to one 'get' route. I need to return some json data and also a view. When attempting to send the data with the view I get an socket.io error message that says I can't send information through views.

```
'get /users': [
        {
          controller: 'UserController',
          action: 'users'
        },
        {
          controller: 'UserController',
          action: 'getuser'
        }
      ],
```

Right now to make it work I have to have two 'get' routes. One that returns my view ejs file and another that the socket can connect too.

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1337');
          socket.get('/user', {}, function(users) {
          var grid = new Slick.Grid("#userGrid", users.users, columns, options);
        });
```

This works but then I have a random /user route out there that anyone can access that just returns json. I'd like to not have random routes that can be accessed through the browser if possible. So can I chain controller actions to one route? Or is there a way to return a res.view and json data in one action?

```
users: function(req, res, next) {
    //User.find().populateAll().exec(function(err, users){
    res.view('user/users');
    next();
    // res.json({
    //   success: true,
    //   users: users
    //    });
    //});
  },

  //get user data and send it as json to for sockets
  getuser: function (req, res) {
    User.find().populateAll().exec(function(err, users) {
      res.json({users: users});
    });
  },
```

I tried using next() and without. Thanks for any help!